# FTP server hanging when transferring file over socket

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, stream

I'm making a simple FTP server in java. I have everything working when I test it locally (running both the server and client on my own machine). When I run the server and client on two different remote machines, however, the client hangs somewhere shortly after it receives the "150 File status okay" message from the server. I can't understand why it works fine in one location but not the other. Here is the relevant code:

Server (sending the file):

```
FileInputStream input = null;
                            try {
                                input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                out.writeBytes("550 File not found or access denied.\r\n");
                            }
                            out.writeBytes("150 File status okay.\r\n");

                            // TCP CONNECT
                            DataOutputStream outToClient_d = null;
                            Socket clientSocket1 = null;

                            try {
                                ipAddress = ipAddress.substring(0,
                                        ipAddress.length() - 1);
                                clientSocket1 = new Socket(ipAddress,
                                        portNumber);
                                outToClient_d = new DataOutputStream(
                                        clientSocket1.getOutputStream());
                            }

                            catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                out.writeBytes("425 Can not open data connection.\r\n");
                            }

                            byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
                            int len;
                            while ((len = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                outToClient_d.write(buf, 0, len);
                            }
                            input.close();

                            out.writeBytes("250 Requested file action completed.\r\n");
                            clientSocket1.close();
                            outToClient_d.close();
```

Client (saving file into /retr_files):

```
InputStream inFromServer_d = null;

    if (welcomeSocket != null) {
        if (!welcomeSocket.isClosed()) {
            welcomeSocket.close();
        }
    }

    try {
        welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.print("PORT " + myIP + "," + num1 + "," + num2 + "\r\n");
        out.writeBytes("PORT " + myIP + "," + num1 + "," + num2 + "\r\n");
        System.out.print(parseReply(getResponse()));
        System.out.print("RETR " + pathname + "\r\n");
        out.writeBytes("RETR " + pathname + "\r\n");
        String reply = parseReply(getResponse());
        if (reply.charAt(10) == '1') {
            System.out.print(reply);
            System.out.print(parseReply(getResponse()));

            try {
                clientSocket_d = welcomeSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out
                        .print("GET failed, FTP-data port not allocated.\r\n");
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            inFromServer_d = clientSocket_d.getInputStream();

            // READ
            InputStream input = inFromServer_d;
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("retr_files/file"
                    + retrCnt);

            byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
            int len;
            while ((len = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
                output.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            input.close();
            output.close();
            clientSocket_d.close();

        } else {
            System.out.print(reply);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("GET failed, FTP-data port not allocated.\r\n");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: would help to know what is that `out` object of yours. Include its declaration and assignment.

Comment: Sorry! Its associated with another socket that writes FTP commands/responses to the server/client.

Comment: how do you determine `myIp` of the client?

Comment: what is the stacktrace of the code when it is hanging?

Comment: So this is odd... The file I was testing this with was a .gif. It worked just fine for a .jpg. Is there something about .gifs that doesn't allow them to transfer as stream of bytes?

Comment: In each `catch` block, after sending the error response, call `out.flush()` and return.  Flushing will ensure that an error message gets through to the client.  Returning will ensure that the server doesn't proceed with trying to do a file transfer on a non-functional connection.  (By the way, debugging will be considerably easier if you either log every exception, or, less ideally, call `printStackTrace()` for every exception.)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess there is a firewall between the client and server blocking the reverse connection from the server to the client.  this problem is the reason that people typically use "passive" transfers instead of "active" transfers these days.

Comment: I don't think so. The two remote machines are both on my school's network (yes, it's a HW assignment... =/ )

Comment: @user1718698 - why does that make it not the problem?  windows often runs a firewall by default, and you can set one up on linux as well.